# php time and hours less than zero (0)

Tags: php, ajax, json

Im displaying on my website the amount of days and hours until a certain event starts, I created the following code:

MY PROBLEM:

Days and hours goes in the minus (less than zero) when there is no days and no hours remaining nothing should be displayed

[image]

```
 //cur date
    $curDate = date("Y-m-d");
        //future date + 7days
        $date = date('Ymd');
        $date = strtotime($date);
        $date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);
        $date =  date('Y-m-d', $date);



     //return days and hours remaining until KO
            $calcDate = $gameDate.$time;
                $calcDate =  strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $gameDate)); 
            $remaining = $calcDate - time();
                $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
                $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
    //echo in index.php display in if statments

    if($days_remaining<0&&$hours_remaining<0){
            echo''; 
            }
    if($days_remaining == 0){
        echo 'Starts In: <span class="timeSpan">'.$hours_remaining.'</span> Hours';
                    }
                    else if($days_remaining != 0){

                        echo' Starts In: <span class="timeSpan">'.$days_remaining.'</span> Days And <span class="timeSpan">'.$hours_remaining.'</span>Hours';           
                    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `if($days_remaining <= 0){` in the last if/else statement?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. What are the time and gameDate?

Comment: @caCtus im gonna give it a go and let you know

Comment: @wonderb0lt time and date is retrieved from a database table events

Comment: If you're interested using TIMESTAMPDIFF() you could get directly the diff between the event_date & now() in minutes by ex. : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4783/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$days_remaining` AND `$hours_remaining` are less than 0, you still go to the last `if/else` statement. As you are not displaying anything if both are less than zero, I'll go in that last `if/else` only if one of them is more than zero:

```
if($days_remaining>0 || $hours_remaining>0){
// You have something to display

    if($days_remaining <= 0){
    // Something with only hours
        echo 'Starts In: <span class="timeSpan">'.$hours_remaining.'</span> Hours';
    }
    else {
    // Something with days and hours
        echo' Starts In: <span class="timeSpan">'.$days_remaining.'</span> Days And <span class="timeSpan">'.$hours_remaining.'</span>Hours';           
    }
}
```

Comment: caCtus im gonna try your code will let you know Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
if($days_remaining == 0){
```

With:

```
if($days_remaining <= 0){
```

This way you will check if the remaining days are 0 or less than 0, and I believe that you will have to add a similar check for the hours that I did not see in your code, but should be the same condition.

Comment: Thanks mate, but im getting same result